How to help lemon tree damaged in a hail storm?
My lemon tree was damaged in a hail storm, it stripped most of the leaves, stripped bark and broke the pot it was in. I put it in a new pot. Is there anything else I should do for it?

Pictures please

I am sorry to hear about your plant. Here are a few things that you can do to help in your plant recovery:
1. Secure the plant, During the time of recovery, place the plant in a place where there is no wind or harsh weather. Also, give it shelter to protect it from sunburn.
2. Pruning, You need to remove any damaged or broken branches to protect the plant from any disease or pests.
3. Patience, Keep performing all the plant care routine and give it some time for recovery. If you give proper care it should start producing new leaves and growth.
I hope your plant gets better soon and best of luck to you.
